# which devdays city was the best?

Tags: discussion, devdays, devdays-2009

Not sure of anyone went to more than one event -- aside from organizers obviously -- hence question can be directed to them. But event was the biggest success in terms of audience, topics, presenters?

Comment: Don't be so exclusionist, there are still two left.

Comment: Opps didn't account for that :))))

Answer (score 2):

Hard to answer, because who other than the organizers (or really just Joel as I only went to 4 myself) has been to *every single DevDays*?

That said, I'd go with London, just based on size. It had 900+ attendees, which is almost 2x as large as the next one, which I believe was Toronto with 500. You need a fairly large group to get the network effects going full swing.

Comment: I hope you got a picture of yourself in Cambridge,Ma and take one in original Cambridge ;) or is Boston one of the ones you missed?

Comment: Among all DevDays I've attended **DevDay London** was definitely the best. ;-)

Comment: The funniest slide was your perception of us Brits ! LOL http://images1.fanpop.com/images/photos/1800000/austin-powers-austin-powers-1872131-973-1230.jpg

Comment: Demand: next DevDay in NY and I am there, at any cost...

Comment: it would be almost worth having one there to meet "the" Sasha. *Almost.* :)